# Specific regex for markdown and links

Tags: ios, swift, regex, swift5

I'm using markdownKit in my iOS App, because it's easier to handle a text
with titles and descriptions.

I created an admin panel for fitness gym, so they can share workouts to their members.
Sometimes, they were added workouts like this:

- Exercise 1
- Exercise 2 etc...

And because of markdown, it's was really messy. So I created this little function, in order to remove special characters (because the purpose there was not to use it for markdown).

```
static func escapeMarkdownCharacters(_ text: String) -> String {
      let modString = text.replacingOccurrences(of: "[#>*\\-+]", with: "\\\\$0", options: [.regularExpression])
      return modString
}
```

My problem now, is that YouTube links are not clickable any more: `https://youtu.be/Z9GZoDq-8JU` becomes `https://youtu.be/Z9GZoDq\-8JU` and the link cannot be opened because of that.

Is there a way to replace occurrences only if it's not in a link ?

Comment: Well, you may use something like `of: "(?<!http\\S{0,255})[#>*+-]"`

Comment: It seems to do the job ! thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may leverage the ICU constrained-width lookbehind pattern:

```swift
of: "(?<!http\\S{0,255})[#>*+-]"
```

Here, it will match

- `(?<!http\S{0,255})` - a location that is not immediately preceded with `http` and 0 to 255 non-whitespace chars
- `[#>*+-]` - either `#`, `>`, `*`, `+` or `-` char.